# Changing Font Style in Minipage

Tags: fonts, minipage, wrapfigure

I am trying to generate a pull quote in my document, which I want to have with a different font style.

To accomplish this, I have a wrapfig environment containing a minipage. I'd like to set the font style to be different just in this minipage.

Below is an MWE; here is what it looks like. I'd like the red quote to be in the Cabin font, for instance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}                      % Define tables and floating elements
\usepackage{flafter}                    % Never put floats before their references
\usepackage{floatflt}                   % wrap text around floats
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    % wrap text around figures
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}                     % Enable colors
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % Lorem Ipsum, for placeholder text.

\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section Heading}\label{sec:mysect}

    %%% If the pull quote comes immediately after a section heading, the next three lines are needed, as well as the line after the paragraph
    \newlength{\tempintextsep}
    \setlength{\tempintextsep}{\intextsep}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    %%
    \begin{wrapfigure}[20]{r}{2.2in}
    \textcolor{red}{
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    $$
    \left\{\;\;\;
    \begin{minipage}{1.65in}
    \centering
    \begingroup
    \fontfamily{Cabin}\selectfont
    \huge
    \textrm{
    \linespread{2}
    Among all of the important things that were ever important, this thing is the most important of all of them; or at least the most important of all of them that appear on this page.
    }
    \endgroup
    \end{minipage}\;\;\;
    \right\}
    $$
    }
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    %% if the pullquote came after a section heading, use the following line
    \setlength{\intextsep}{\tempintextsep}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `usenames`.  `dvipsnames` will cover it for you.

Comment: I also came across an issue with font spacing in math mode. If I get out of math mode, I lose the braces, but I can control font spacing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the package `cabin` changes only the sans serif font family. So you can just replace `\textrm` with `\textsf` and remove the line

```
\fontfamily{Cabin}\selectfont
```

Complete MWE (note that I've just changed the number of `wrapfig` lines from 20 to 22, no other changes as the one suggested by Dustin)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}                      % Define tables and floating elements
\usepackage{flafter}                    % Never put floats before their references
\usepackage{floatflt}                   % wrap text around floats
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    % wrap text around figures
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}                     % Enable colors
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % Lorem Ipsum, for placeholder text.

\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section Heading}\label{sec:mysect}

    %%% If the pull quote comes immediately after a section heading, the next three lines are needed, as well as the line after the paragraph
    \newlength{\tempintextsep}
    \setlength{\tempintextsep}{\intextsep}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    %%
    \begin{wrapfigure}[22]{r}{2.2in}
    \textcolor{red}{
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    $$
    \left\{\;\;\;
    \begin{minipage}{1.65in}
    \centering
    \begingroup
    \huge
    \linespread{2}
    \textsf{%
    Among all of the important things that were ever important, this thing is the most important of all of them; or at least the most important of all of them that appear on this page.
    }
    \endgroup
    \end{minipage}\;\;\;
    \right\}
    $$
    }
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    %% if the pullquote came after a section heading, use the following line
    \setlength{\intextsep}{\tempintextsep}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I never knew about `textsf`!

Answer (score 3):

Your main error is here

```
\begingroup
\fontfamily{Cabin}\selectfont
\huge
\textrm{
\linespread{2}
Among all of the important things that were ever important, this thing is the most important of all of them; or at least the most important of all of them that appear on this page.
}
\endgroup
```

whenever you have a font size change you must always ensure the end of paragraph is in the same scope otherwise you get large text set to a small baseline and wildly uneven line spacing as you show. You don't need the grouping anyway as minipage will group it for you

```
 \begin{minipage}{1.65in}
\centering
\fontfamily{Cabin}\huge
\linespread{2}
Among all of the important things that were ever important, this thing is the most important of all of them; or at least the most important of all of them that appear on this page.
\end{minipage}
```

should work so long as you have `\fontfamily{Cabin}` set up

Comment: Thanks! I found issues pertaining to the grouping, too, but I never knew about the end of paragraph thing.