# Environment with smaller text loses line spacing in second paragraph

Tags: spacing, environments, fontsize

I have made an environment to get sections of text with smaller size and formatting. But when I use two paragraphs it seems to forget the linespacing from the first one (which I would like to keep).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{packed}
{\bigskip
  \noindent
  \small
 \( \aleph \)}
{\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{packed}
  First paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

  Second paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{packed}
\end{document}
```

[image: second paragraph has more line spacing]

Comment: this is a faq (must be a duplicate here) you need `\par` before the `\bigskip` so that the paragraph ends before the size change goes out of scope

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148508/how-does-fontsize-work

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131924/changing-font-style-in-minipage/131926#131926

Comment: Thanks! Should I close this somehow? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @trmdttr no it's fine, the system automatically links it to earlier questions on the same subject and having multiple such questions with different wording is a good thing helps increase chance of google searches finding something in future.